# the_content() won't load galleries on homepage

Tags: gallery, homepage, the-content

I need to show a gallery that's on the content of one of the pages I'm displaying on the homepage (I altered the query so it would display pages instead of posts). If I open the page directly I can see the gallery but on the homepage I can only see the text around it.

This is the code I used to modify the home loop:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'setup_site_loop' );
function setup_site_loop( $query ) {
  if ( is_home() ) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'seccion'); 
    $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order title'); 
    $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
  }
}
```

Here's the home.php

```
<div id="main" class="clearfix" role="main">

  <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    <article id="section-<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>" <?php post_class( 'clearfix' ); ?> role="article">

    <section class="entry-content clearfix">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </section>

  </article>

   endwhile;
  endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include **all relevant code**, in context. I'm guessing that "*I altered the query so it would display pages instead of posts*" is probably a good place to start.

Comment: I added the code from functions.php and home.php. I don't kinow if it'd have anything to do with the galleries not displaying in my homepage.

Comment: What are your settings under `Settings - Reading`, for **Front page displays**, **Front page**, and **Posts page**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here, but I'm not sure that any one directly is your problem. First, you need to be more specific in your `pre_get_posts` callback conditional, to ensure you're targeting only the main query. Second, you need to clarify the post type you're intending to show.

Third - and the one that may be causing the most problems of all - it is rare to need to change the post-type to display on the *blog posts index* (i.e. `is_home()`), rather than on the *site front page* (i.e. `is_front_page()`)

### Query Conditional

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'setup_site_loop' );
function setup_site_loop( $query ) {
  if ( is_home() ) {
    $query->set('post_type', 'seccion'); 
    $query->set('orderby', 'menu_order title'); 
    $query->set('order', 'ASC'); 
  }
}
```

This line:

```
if ( is_home() ) {
```

Two things:

1. Add a check for `is_main_query()`, since there will almost always be multiple queries on any given page
2. When testing query conditionals, target `$query` directly

   ```
   if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
   ```

### Post Type

This line:

```
$query->set('post_type', 'seccion');
```

You're setting the post-type to `'seccion'`, but according to your Question:

> (I altered the query so it would display pages instead of posts)

Is `'seccion'` a custom post type? Is it the intended post type to display, or do you really intend to display `page` post-type?

### Home vs Front Page

I suspect that the real issue is that you're targeting the wrong query conditional. If your front page is set to display the blog posts index, then your query conditional should be fine. But if your site front page is set to display a static page, and you're intending to target that static site front page, your query conditional is wrong. You will need to target [`is_front_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) instead of [`is_home()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_home):

```
if ( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page() ) {
```

For [more information regarding home vs front page, see here](http://www.chipbennett.net/2013/09/14/home-page-and-front-page-and-templates-oh-my/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. It worked and it's a very good explanation on Wordpress Loops.